# Can't get a specific regex to work in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string formatted like:

```
project-version-project_test-type-other_info-other_info.file_type
```

I can strip most of the information I need out of this string in most cases. My trouble arises when my version has an extra qualifying character in it (i.e. normally 5 characters but sometimes a 6th is added).

Previously, I was using substrings to remove the excess information and get the 'project_test-type' however, now I need to switch to a regex (mostly to handle that extra version character). I could keep using substrings and change the length depending on whether I have that extra version character or not but a regex seems more appropriate here.

I tried using patterns like:

```
my ($type) = $_ =~ /.*-.*-(.*)-.*/;
```

But the extra '-' in the 'project_test-type' means I can't simply space my regex using that character.

**What regex can I use to get the 'project_test-type' out of my string?**

---

More information:
As a more human readable example, the information is grouped in the following way:

```
project - version - project_test-type - other_info - other_info . file_type
```

- 'project' is a simple string of chars
- 'version' is normally a string of 5 integers, but is sometimes followed by a char, i.e. 11111 is normal and 11111A is the rarer occurence.
- 'project_test-type' is a specific test associated with a project that can have both '_' and '-' in it's otherwise char name
- Both cases of 'other_info' are additional bits of information for the system like an IP address or another version number. The first has no fixed length while the second is always 10 characters long

Comment: Can you please add which values are possible for project-version, other_info etc.?

Comment: can you give example for normally 5 and sometimes 6?

Comment: @karthikmanchala normally version is 11111 and sometimes version is 11111A

Comment: Ok about the greediness etc. it all depends on your data which one is the best solution... if you also have `-` in other info it could be impossible.

Comment: @maraca I added more info. The 'other_info' never has a `-` in it . But it can have `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no field other than the desired one can contain `-`, any extra `-` belongs to the desired field.

```
      +--------------------------- project
      |     +--------------------- version
      |     |   +----------------- project_test-type
      |     |   |      +---------- other_info
      |     |   |      |     +---- other_info.file_type
      |     |   |      |     |
  ____| ____|  _|  ____| ____|
/^[^-]*-[^-]*-(.*)-[^-]*-[^-]*\z/
```

`[^-]` matches a character that's not a `-`.
`[^-]*` matches zero or more characters that's aren't `-`.

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

To match everything:

```
/^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(.+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

`[]` defines character sets and `^` at the beginning of a set means "NOT". Also a `-` in a set usually means a range, unless it is at the beginning or end. So `[^-]+` consumes as many non-dash characters as possible (at least one).

Comment: But it was a great attempt. Thanks for the help. ikegami's solution is just a little cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/\w+\s*-\s*\d{5}[a-zA-Z]?\s*-\s*(.*?)(?=\s*-\s*\d)/
```

Explanation:

- `\w+\s*-` ==> match character sequence followed by any number of spaces and a `-`
- `\d{5}[a-zA-Z]?` ==> always 5 digits with one or zero character
- `(.*?)` => match everything in a non greedy way
- `(?=\s*-\s*\d)` => look forward for a digit and stop (since IP starts with a digit)

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/eU4dX6/3)

Comment: Could you include more of an explanation in your answer than just an external link? It is helpful but it's nice to protect against link-rot.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Updated answer for your specs and added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Greedy/non-greedy approach

```
($type) = /.*?-.*?-(.*)-.*-.*/;
```

`.*?` is a non-greedy match, meaning match any number of any character, but no more than necessary to match the regular expression. Using `.*` between the second and third dashes is a greedy match, matching as many characters as possible while still matching the regular expression, and using this will capture words with any extra dashes in them.